# VSCode does not format JSX Correctly

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, code-formatting

If I have:

```
<Button
  onClick={ this.handleCreateFormOpen }
/>
```

And I type `SHIFT` + `OPTION` + `F`

Then my JSX is formatted like so:

```
<Button
  onClick={this.handleCreateFormOpen}
/>
```

I want this:    `onClick={ this.handleCreateFormOpen }`

I am Android Dev and in Android Studio I can change the formatting as i choose, is there an option like that in VSCode?

I want to be able to type `SHIFT` + `OPTION` + `F` and VSCode format my code like `onClick={ this.handleCreate }` instead of `onClick={this.handleCreateFormOpen}` is this possible?

Comment: `onClick={this.handleCreateFormOpen}` is the standard format for props. Depending on the formatter used, you'll likely see `{ key: value }` with object literals.

Comment: Like Emile says, what you have is correct formatting.

Comment: But I don't want it to be. I am Android Dev and in Android Studio I can change the formatting as i choose, theres nothing like that in VSCode? I want to be able to type ```SHIFT``` + ```OPTION``` + ```F``` and VSCode format my code like ```onClick={ this.handleCreate }``` is this possible?

Comment: This is a valid question please upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the space-in-brackets rule to your eslint config.

```
"space-in-brackets": ["error", "always"]
```

> space-in-brackets: enforce consistent spacing inside braces of object literals and brackets of array literals

Example of incorrect code for this rule with the "always" option:

```js
<Button
   onClick={this.handleCreateFormOpen}
/>
```

Example of correct code for this rule with the "always" option:

```js
<Button
  onClick={ this.handleCreateFormOpen }
/>
```

More information and details: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-in-brackets

Comment: Awesome! Please upvote my question. I am very surprised because people didn't know how to answer my question that they down voted it. It's a very valid question. Thanks again!!!